# Is there anyway to filter all ORM queries in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm, django-middleware, django-2.0

So I have a rather unorthodox idea of using a middleware to filter queries dynamically, as to keep my authentication further away from the views themselves. I've seen a few library's that could log transactions, but there's no way to alter them since it's post-transaction.

Essentially any calls to a certain model would be filtered based on authentication credentials. *E.g. Some field that states a user's privileges.*

This is probably **insane** and would require me hooking into the ORM itself, but I must ask out of curiosity. Maybe I'm just too lazy to change the rest of my code to reflect this.

Thanks to anybody who could clarify if this is possible or impossible.

**Edit:**
As of writing this question... Wouldn't this be possible to achieve by subclassing a model manager? *Am I this thick?!*

Comment: Are you looking at writing your own [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/)?

Comment: I think so. See my edit.

Comment: Oh right yeah, it sounds as though you can achieve this with your own manager..

Comment: My one question is can I get the request object inside it?

Comment: Ah not really because you're not guarranteed that a db query is being done from a request (i.e migrations/middleware/logging)

Comment: That's true. Hmm, I'll have to scheme and maybe do a little hacking. Maybe I could use signals? I'm pulling at straws now, haha.

Comment: Not sure if this is an updated library but https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-contrib-requestprovider looks promising.